# opengl code compilation issue

Tags: opengl, graphics

After drawing a shape am not been able to draw any more shapes in my display function. But it is being drawn perfectly in other methods but not in my glutidlefunction(myDispalay). Stuck here for about two days. can anyone help me out from here ?

Here is the code :

```
include < stdio.h>

include< math.h>

include < GL/glut.h>

define PI 3.1416

float x,y,r,y2,r2;

void drawCircle(float x, float y, float radius)

{
    int i;

    int triangleAmount = 1000; //# of triangles used to draw circle

    float twicePi = 2.0f * PI;

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);

    for(i = 0; i <= triangleAmount;i++)

    {
        glVertex2f( x + (radius * cos(i * twicePi / triangleAmount)),
            y + (radius * sin(i * twicePi / triangleAmount)));
    }
    glEnd();
}

void drawthrower()

{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glColor3f(0.0,1.0,0.0);
    drawCircle(x,y,r);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex2i(x-12,y-28);
        glVertex2i(x-12,y-70);

        glVertex2i(x+12,y-28);
        glVertex2i(x+12,y-70);
    glEnd();
    drawCircle(x,y2,r2);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void myDisplay()
{

       while ((x+r)<=1024)
        {
            x+=8;
            drawthrower();
        }

     while ((x-r)>=0)
       {
            x-=8;
            drawthrower();
       }

}


void myInit()
{

    glClearColor(1,1,1,1);

    x=50,y=693,r=30,x=50,y2=623,r2=12;

}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{

   glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);

   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

   glLoadIdentity();

   glOrtho(0.0, 1024.0, 0.0, 768.0, 0.0, 1.0);

   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

}


int main(int argc, char** argv)

{

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(1024,768);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow("Graphics_Project");
    myInit();
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutIdleFunc(myDisplay);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You need to call `glutSwapBuffers()` only once per frame, at the end of your main display function.

Comment: In this code i have drawn an abject and constantly moving the object along x axis within the visible range. By calling glutSwapBuffers() once at the end in my main display function doesn't solving my problem here. It Isn't drawing any new shapes on the screen and even stopping the movement of my preiviously drawn shape. I have also tried using single buffer but also it's extracting the same problem

Answer (score 0):

When using GLUT drawing code should be isolated to the display callback function. You're currently have the display function registered as idle function. To make the program call the display function continuously call glutPostRedisplay from the idle function (or register glutPostRedisplay *as* the idle function). The reason why you should limit drawing code to the display callback is, that depending on the OS when the redraw event is sent certain special state may be set.

Also, while not technically wrong, but a stylistic issue is, that the glutSwapBuffers should be moved into the display function, so that when maintaining the program one does not go hunting for details like in which subroutine the buffer swap is carried out.

Comment: In this code i have drawn an abject and constantly moving the object along x axis within the visible range. By calling glutSwapBuffers() once at the end in my main display function doesn't solving my problem here. It Isn't drawing any new shapes on the screen and even stopping the movement of my preiviously drawn shape. I have also tried using single buffer but also it's extracting the same problem. But i am perfectly generating exact output if i draw something on other methods in drawthrower()/draw circle() except in myDisplay().

Comment: `#include "mongo/client/dbclient.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
using namespace mongo;

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
    cout<<"good so far"<<endl;
    client::GlobalInstance instance; //everytime producing segmentation fault 
    if (!instance.initialized()) {
        std::cout << "failed to initialize the client driver: " << instance.status() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
 else
 {
   std::cout << "Successfully initialized the client driver: " << instance.status() << std::endl;
 }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}`